# How can I implement probability prediction for One vs One classifier specifically in Sklearn?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

I am trying to get probability instead of hard prediction by a One vs One classifier. It is not supported by Sklearn implicitly. Is there nay way to implement it by myself? If so please explain?

For instance the thing in mid is getting scores per classifier and summing them up per class then l1 norm these scores to get a prob values. Do you think this is right intuition ?

Answer (score 1):

It's already one method for classifiers in development version. You can take the risk to use them.

It provides more precise probability value than other classifiers with probability value by regression

http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/calibration.html

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6164) issue, looks like it is recommended to use the `decision_function()` in such a case.

For example:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 1], [-2, 1], [-2, -1]])
y = np.array([2, 0, 1, 2])

multi_clf = OneVsOneClassifier(Perceptron(shuffle=False))
ovo_prediction = multi_clf.fit(X, y).predict(X)

ovo_decision = multi_clf.decision_function(X)

votes = np.round(ovo_decision)
normalized_confidences = ovo_decision - votes
```